# How to add an application context in apache2

Tags: apache-2.2

Let's say I have a virtual host with a ServerName directive like so:

`ServerName geekspeak.dev`

And in my hosts file:

`127.0.1.1 geekspeak.dev`

Now when I enter `geekspeak.dev` in my browser, I'm directed to my application running on localhost. Simple.

But what if instead of `geekspeak.dev`, I want to require users to enter `geekspeak.dev/foo` to get to my app. Is there an apache directive or some other technique that will allow me to accomplish this?

Thanks!

**Edit**

I tried adding an empty `DocumentRoot` and an `Alias` as suggested by Shi, but I had no success. I wonder if the fact that it's acting as a proxy has anything to do with it? I've pasted my virtual host below, maybe someone can see what's wrong with it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName geekspeak.dev

  DocumentRoot /var/www/foo
  Alias /foo /var/www/foo

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm expecting this to reach my app at `/` but instead it reaches my app at `/foo`

Comment: do you get any workaround? I also want to do same (hide application context path from end user using apache 2)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you use `DocumentRoot` inside your virtual host pointing to your application.

For "drop-in" installation of applications I suggest you simply use an empty directory as `DocumentRoot`, or whatever content should be available there, and use [`Alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) to point to your application.

```
Alias /foo /var/www/web-application
```

Comment: I can't get this to work properly. I've updated my question to include the contents of the virtual host. Let me know if anything stands out. Thanks!

Comment: @Samo: Having both `DocumentRoot` and `Alias` pointing to the same directory looks VERY strange. `/excluded` is served from `geekspeak.dev`, so right now it has to be located in the filesystem at `/var/www/foo/excluded`. Maybe that's right, maybe not, I do not know. Anyway, you proxy everything, including `/foo` to `127.0.0.1:9000`. Simply `ProxyPass /foo !` to not proxy your application.